# Ordering Dictionary Values in Python

Tags: python

How can I order the values for my dictionary?

```
            sorted_activities = sorted(activity_dicc.items(),reverse=True)
            for activity,duration in sorted_activities :
                    print(activity,duration)
```

activity_dicc is my dictionary, activity is the key and duration is the value.

When I run my code, it is not sorted. I hoped for it to appear in order by the duration going from highest to lowest.

(The code is way too long to show, but that's the part with the issue. I need to set up a place so it knows how to sort it by, but I'm not sure where to do that.)

Comment: It'll be sorted by *keys*, not values. You'll need to define a `key=` function for `sorted` that sorts by the *second item in a tuple*.

Comment: The IDE/editor you use is irrelevant to questions like this.  tag deleted.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot sort dictionaries. By definition they are unsorted key-value pairs. You should create a sorted list with the dictionary keys and run a loop to print the dictionary values that match the keys.

```
sorted_activities = sorted(activity_dicc.keys(), reverse=True)
for activity in sorted_activities:
    print(activity_dicc[activity])
```

Comment: OP *is* attempting to sort a dict by turning it into a sorted list of items…!